# How to rename paths within files in gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp

If I have multiple script tags in my index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />
<script src="myjs/js.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to write a gulp task that looks at all html files, and appends "mydir/" to the front of all paths such that the output file (of the same name) i.e. index.html is still index.html.
So when I open the file if I look at the paths, I see

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mydir/style/style.css" />
<script src="mydir/myjs/js.js"></script>
```

I know there is a gulp-rename, but it looks to only rename files and not contents of files.

Comment: would it worth to use base tag?

Comment: not sure what you mean...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Answer (score 0):

Making this the actual answer -

```
<base href="mydir/">
```

You don't need gulp to do this for you.